# Django Language Switcher Not Showing Check Next to Current Language

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a language switcher where I can't use a form directly.  Here is the code:

```
<li class="hoverSelector">
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    <a>Languages</a>
    <ul class="languages hoverSelectorBlock">
        {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        <li><a href="#" lang-code="{{ lang.0 }}" class="change_language" {% if get_current_language == lang.0 %}selected="selected" {% else %} selected="" {% endif %}>{{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

Then I have this form:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: none" id="change_language_form">
{% csrf_token %}
    <select type="hidden">
        <option type="hidden" id="language-option" value=""></option>
    </select>
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.path }}" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="language" id="language" />
</form>
```

Then the jQuery form the form:

```
<script>
    $('.change_language').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#language').val($(this).attr('lang-code'));
        $('#language-option').val($(this).attr('lang-code'));
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('i.fa-check').remove();
        if ($(this).attr('selected') === 'selected')
        {
            $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');    
        }
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        $('#change_language_form').submit();
    });    
</script>
```

The code works, and changes the language, but I cannot seem to get the check mark to appear next to the current language once the page reloads.  I tried adding

```
if ($('.change_language').attr('selected') === 'selected')
{
    $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
}
```

At the bottom of the jQuery I showed earlier, but still it doesn't show the check mark next to the correct language after reload, and it makes it so the other JavaScript doesn't seem to work at all. No check marks appear.

Without that code it does show the correct check mark when I click the the language, and then if I click another it moves the check mark.  But as I said after page reload, the check mark is gone.

What can I do to make it mark the current language?  What am I missing?

Thanks, any help is much appreciated

Comment: It sounds like your view is passing the wrong `get_current_language` value, which is selecting the language without even checking which one it is. You could either change that value in your view, or run a javascript function that runs on page load that detects the current language and auto-configures the check marks.

Comment: It does translate the language list correctly. Just doesn't check off the language that is current despite the JavaScript. What could I change to fix this. It's obviously translating correctly but not checking off the current language. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't believe your last js block is valid; you are using `this` improperly. Try doing something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLp369my/) - it loops over each element within the `.change_language` class and checks each individual element for your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding this under the  jQuery:

```
$('.current_language').parent().addClass('active');
$('.current_language').append('<i class="fa fa-check"></i>');
```

adding this template tag:

`{% get_current_language as current_lang %}`

and then this to the class of the anchors within the `<li>`'s in the languages dropdown.

`class="change_language{% if current_lang == lang.0 %} current_language {% endif %}"`